# What is the benefit of having dynamic configuration in FPGA PLL?

Tags: fpga, pll

With PLL it is possible to generate clock signal at different frequencies and phase values. So far I have seen that these settings are done at design time and do not have to be changed during run time.

When does a need arise to be able to change the PLL settings and run time? PLLs in modern FPGAs are quite complex and have a lot of settings that can be used to configure its behaviour.

Comment: It boils down to this: is there any type of digital clocked circuit that can gain benefit from running the clock at a different speed at certain times. It's not specific to PLLs because those digital circuits that gain benefit may not use PLLs but, of course they could. On the same basis, your question isn't really to do specifically with the usage of an FPGA; it could be any digital tech that gains a benefit.

Comment: PLLs have quite a lot of complex options and configurations. Therefore, I am quite sure that it is not just changing the clock frequency that would be done dynamically.

Comment: You might want to vary clock rate to match power consumption to throughput. You might want to be able to flexibly interface with different sources or sinks that have different clock rates. Or you might not, in which case there's no benefit.